# Covariance of a covariance matrix

Tags: self-study, covariance-matrix

Given that covariance matrix, why is the covariance of Y and Z in this case "(-1 0)" or what would be the covariance of X and Y?

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain what "covariance of Y and Z of the covariance matriz" means?